# Adding space between images?

Tags: html, css, image

I have this div:

```
<div id="barraLinhas">
    <img onclick="linhaAzul()" src="Linha_Azul.png" value="Linha Azul" />
    <img onclick="linhaAmarela()" src="Linha_Amarela.png" value="Linha Amarela" />
    <img onclick="linhaVerde()" src="Linha_Verde.png" value="Linha Verde" />
    <img onclick="linhaVermelha()" src="Linha_Vermelha.png" value="Linha Vermelha" />
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#barraLinhas {
    width: 950px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

And I would like to have those images with spaces between them but I am having trouble doing so (it is probably stupid easy.. I am just being dumb).

EDIT: Or even have them spaced in those 950px

Comment: where's your img css? Is it block or inline ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wanted space between them, you can use `+` sibling selector to target image margin if only a image is present after the current image.

```css
#barraLinhas {
  width: 950px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#barraLinhas img + img {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="barraLinhas">
  <img onclick="linhaAzul()" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" value="Linha Azul" />
  <img onclick="linhaAmarela()" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" value="Linha Amarela" />
  <img onclick="linhaVerde()" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" value="Linha Verde" />
  <img onclick="linhaVermelha()" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" value="Linha Vermelha" />
</div>
```

Comment: just using img and :first-child would be better yet.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Yup! Many ways to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
#barraLinhas img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

this will put them under barraLinhas from left to right, with 10px space between them

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox:

```css
#barraLinhas {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
#barraLinhas {
  width: 950px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="barraLinhas">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Linha Azul" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Linha Amarela" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Linha Verde" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Linha Vermelha" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use CSS like so:

```
img{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kqpn27ec/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#barraLinhas img:not(:first-child){
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

or

```
#barraLinhas img:nth-child(n+2){
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```